# In my study of Inferential Statistics, the following uses of inferences were mentioned. Could this be expanded upon?

Tags: inference, engineering-statistics

Currently an undergraduate engineering student studying Statistics. My source has cited three major uses of inferences:

Types of Inferences

- Estimation - The value of a parameter is estimated.
- Testing - A decision is formulated about the value of a parameter.
- Regression - Predictions or forecasts about the value of a statistical variable are made.

It got me interested since I have already read other sources prior that the two main fields of inferential statistics are parameter estimation and hypothesis testing. This one added the regression.

So my question is, to anyone who is actually already experienced in statistics, how would you classify inferences on a wider scale? I mean would you be able to give more categories even though they are not mainly used? Categories as in the usage of inferences. I just like having an overview of what inferential statistics is while going through the topics. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe expand on 'estimation' with confidence intervals, and branch from there to bootstrapping. // Maybe consider Bayesian inference to be on your list or parallel with it. // Exploratory data analysis // Machine learning. // Not sure about the structure of your list and what you'd want to put on it. Google a bit, then decide/

Comment: I'm not that specific with what I would want to put but I would be interested if there were other main branches that would be added or if those three have already covered everything and the big topics can be classified under them.

Comment: Well, I mentioned a few in my previous comment that I might put on _my_ list.